Existence of periodic orbits in $\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x < -1\right\}$
Considering the system
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = 2x + x^2 + y^2,$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = x^2 - y^2$$
and the region $D = \left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x < -1\right\}$, I have to study the existence of periodic orbits in $D$. Trying to apply Bendixson criterion, the divergence of $f(x, y) = \left(2x + x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2\right)$ for $(x, y) \in D$, we have that
$$\text{div}(f)(x, y) = 2(1 + x - y),$$
so I can't say anything about its sign in $D$. Indeed, I can say there are no periodic orbits in the regions such that $y < x + 1$ or $y > x + 1$. Then what about $D$?

Maybe you have a typo - closed orbits require encircling fixed points. There are no fixed points for $x < -1$.

@DanAsimov If $-2 \leq x < -1$ then $2x + x^2 = x(2 + x) \leq 0$.

Sorry about that.

@DanAsimov Don't worry. :)

@Gregory You're right! Do you come up with any other idea without using that result?

As Gregory suggested, look for any common zeroes of dx/dt and dy/dt. If there are none with x < -1, then there cannot be any closed orbit in region D. Because if there were one, there would also be a zero of the vector field inside such a closed orbit — which would be a zero in D — contradiction.
